# Class not found in PHP - Scope Resolution

Tags: php

I got 2 PHP files:

courier.php

```
    <?php
namespace Shipping;

class Courier
{
    public $name;
    public $home_country;

    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
        return true;
    }

    public function ship($parcel) {
        // sends the parcel to  its destination
        return true;
    }

    public static function getCouriersByCountry($country) {
        // get a list of couriers with their home_country = $country

        // create a Courier object for each result

        // return an array of the results
        return $courier_list;

    }

}
?>
```

filephp.php

```
<?php
//namespace Fred;

require 'courier.php';
//function __autoload($classname) {
//    include //strtolower($classname).'.php';
//}

$mono = new Shipping\Courier('Monospace Delivery');

//var_dump($mono);

// accessing a property
echo "Courier Name: " . $mono->name;

// calling a method
$mono->ship($parcel);

$spanish_couriers = Courier::getCouriersByCountry('Spain');

echo $spanish_couriers;
?>
```

But when I execute filephp.php I get this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Courier' not found in D:\masterphp\test.php on line 19

line 19 is this:

```
$spanish_couriers = Courier::getCouriersByCountry('Spain');
```

What is wrong with my scope resolution?

Comment: Directory is same??? For courier.php

Comment: all files in same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the Shipping namespace, it should be \Shipping\Courier::...